# jsonLD to graphical representationnot working

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, ontology, json-ld, graph-visualization

I am trying to draw a graph from my ontology which is in RDF format.I am following "https://github.com/scienceai/jsonld-vis" repositry to develop.I am getting error when trying to replicate the above github code.I am adding my code for the aobve implemetation [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/3u4LwQyNZaaJgNR2Dgli?p=catalogue)

I came across many comments saying above github repositry works.But i am not to figure it out. Please help

```
d3.jsonldVis(mockData, '#graph', {
  w: 800,
  h: 600,
  maxLabelWidth: 250,
  tipClassName: 'tip-class'
});
```

If there are any other libraries i can use to implement the above in angularjs,javascript environment please mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is to be answered but anyway with minor changes the example can be reproduced:

**Minor Changes:**

1. The MAIN code to initiate **jsonld-vis** `index.js` wasn't being included
2. CSS included as a script??? Probably a mistake. Added a `link` tag to include it.
3. The library is based on d3 version 3 and you were trying to include the latest (i.e. v5.6)
4. You don't need to use the `import` statements here. Read more about import [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) or [here](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/a-simple-intro-to-javascript-imports-and-exports-389dd53c3fac)

Fork: https://plnkr.co/edit/KkNHWQa0xxiotB4tN7Ru?p=preview

Suggestions? [d3 Collapsible Tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) is a great viz that you can refer to and customize as per your requirements.